# Mix and Match - SQL query to apply cheapest offers to items in cart

Tags: php, mysql, sql, innodb

After the user adds an item to the cart i would like to check if the current cart has an offer or offers of **mix and match** that can be applied to it. if the item has multiple offers the offer that is cheapest will be applied. an item can only have one offer applied to it. but if the quantity of the item is more than the offer then the quantity left can be applied to other offers.

This is how far i've come

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(tl.tl_id) lineIds,
    mm.mm_offer,
    SUM(tl.tl_price * tl.tl_quantity) AS originalPrice,
    mm.mm_offerPrice,
    (
        SUM(tl.tl_price * tl.tl_quantity) - mm.mm_offerPrice
    ) AS diff,
    mm.mm_numberOfItems,
    mm.mm_numberOfLines,
    SUM(
        (mm.mm_numberOfItems * mm.mm_numberOfLines) - tl.tl_quantity
    ) 'left'
FROM
    posTransactionLine AS tl
    JOIN posMixMatch AS mm ON tl.tl_itemNumber = mm.mm_item
WHERE
    tl.tl_th_id = ?
    AND(
        CURDATE() BETWEEN mm.mm_activeFrom
        AND mm.mm_activeTo
    )
GROUP BY
    mm.mm_offer,
    mm.mm_offerPrice,
    mm.mm_numberOfItems,
    mm.mm_numberOfLines
HAVING
    SUM(tl.tl_quantity) >= mm.mm_numberOfItems
    AND SUM(tl.tl_quantity) >= mm.mm_numberOfLines
ORDER BY
    SUM(tl.tl_price * tl.tl_quantity) - mm.mm_offerPrice DESC
```

example data

```
[
    {
        "mm_offer": "MM00023",
        "mm_item": "55202206",
        "mm_group": " ",
        "mm_numberOfItems": "1",
        "mm_numberOfLines": "2",
        "mm_activeFrom": "2021-09-01",
        "mm_activeTo": "2023-12-31",
        "mm_description": "Armband 2 för 50:-",
        "mm_offerPrice": "50.00",
        "mm_priority": "0"
    },
    {
        "mm_offer": "MM000231",
        "mm_item": "55202206",
        "mm_group": " ",
        "mm_numberOfItems": "1",
        "mm_numberOfLines": "2",
        "mm_activeFrom": "2021-09-01",
        "mm_activeTo": "2023-12-31",
        "mm_description": "Armband 2 för 10:-",
        "mm_offerPrice": "10.00",
        "mm_priority": "0"
    }
]
```

Comment: What you want to do is quite complex. Without knowing what your database looks like, what it all means, and perhaps even some examples, it will be extremely hard to help you.

Comment: Please include a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: SQL is not a very expressive language for complex stuff.  Consider doing the logic in your app.